# AWS CodeDeploy and CodePipeline Using S3 bucket content as Source

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy

I am using AWS CodePipeline to deploy to an EC2 instance whenever there's a file change in my S3 bucket. Currently the Code Pipeline automatically kicks off a deployment only when I make a change to a file inside of a specific zip folder inside the S3 bucket (`SampleApp_Linux.zip`).

[image]This is inconvenient when using AWS CDK, because I have to unzip the object, make changes to my file, and then zip it again before pushing changes. I also can't see my files in the zipped folder from a code repo.

I'm wondering is there a way to have CodePipeline automatically start deployments whenever there's a change to any file in the S3 bucket and not just those inside of the zip folder (ie changes to `myDummyFiles` folder)?

**Update:**
I am creating all of these resources via AWS CDK and using the `bucketDeployment` resource to push my S3 file changes in `SampleApp_Linux` folder to CDK. If it isn't possible for Pipelines to track unzipped changes to S3 perhaps AWS CDK can zip the `SampleApp_Linux` folder for me before it deploys it to AWS. That way CodePipeline will pick up the change.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_s3_deployment.BucketDeployment.html

Attached are screenshots of my CodePipeline SourceAction and S3 bucket.

[image]

Comment: You can kick off a lambda on S3 changes to a path prefix (or the entire bucket) and the lambda can call [StartPipelineExecution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/APIReference/API_StartPipelineExecution.html) so you could do that.  But "I have to unzip the object, make changes to my file, and then zip it again before pushing changes" this Zip file should probably be built from the code repo on push to the main branch and then you don't have to build out a lambda event.

Comment: That's an interesting suggestion. How could I have the zipfile be built from the code repo on push though? I'm imagining instead of just running `"git push"`, running a script that zips the folder content and then does git push. But not sure if that's a good way to go about it.

Comment: Yeah build it when you push.  If you're using github, github actions is a good choice.  You can use github's Web Identity to access an IAM role so you can push the zip to S3

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option:  Configure your [pipeline source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codepipeline_actions-readme.html#sources) to run on changes to your code repo.  Next, add a `BucketDeployment` construct to the pipeline.  On each pipeline run, the `BucketDeployment` bundles your `SampleApp_Linux` code and saves it to a S3 bucket.

The [BucketDeployment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_s3_deployment-readme.html) construct automagically (using a Custom Resource) will create your code artefact from the `source` path and copy it to a `destinationBucket`.  The `extract: false` setting tells the CDK not to unzip the artefact at the S3 destination.

```js
new BucketDeployment(this, "LinuxAppDeployment", {
    sources: [Source.asset(path.join(__dirname, "./path/to/SampleApp_Linux"))],
    destinationBucket: bucket,
    extract: false,
});
```

Comment: That makes sense but won't sources: `[Source.asset(path.join(__dirname, "./path/to/SampleApp_Linux"))]`, just upload an unzipped folder into S3 and thus not start the pipeline because the pipeline only runs on changes to SampleApp_Linux.zip? I believe that the for the CodePipeline S3 ActionSource it has to be a zip file to trigger the pipeline. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codepipeline_actions-readme.html#aws-s3-source

Comment: @dredbound - my suggestion is to use a repo source action like `GitHubSourceAction`, not the S3 Source Action, to trigger your pipeline.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not possible for me. I have to use S3 as my repo source.

Comment: @dredbound  Understood.  The S3 action is tied to a single S3 file as defined in the `bucketKey` prop.  No worries.  If you add a step-by-step description of your workflow to your question, we can work on the alternatives.